# force encoding off for one service?

Tags: servicestack, gzip

I am trying to implement an RSS feed that is linked through an Outlook client. The feed works on every machine except my development machine.  When looking at the results coming back from the service, it is clear that my machine is getting data returned encoded via gzip, and the Outlook client doesn't look like it's smart enough to decompress.  Is there any way I can examine the request headers in the service and make sure this particular service output is never compressed?

NOTE: I am not using the cache or ever calling .ToCompressedResult.  My service generates xml using an XMLWriter and returns that xml as a string. I have [AddHeader(ContentType = MimeTypes.XmlText)] on the service as well. So I'm not even sure why the result is coming back compressed.

Client that doesn't work

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.056 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2016 20:57:39 GMT
Content-Length: 539
```

Client that works

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Vary: Accept
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.056 Win32NT/.NET
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    Set-Cookie: ss-id=YVha5gBKFgrsMLJiOFDs; path=/; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: ss-pid=WQBwbdU2txHLhgZLbRwR; expires=Sat, 21-Jun-2036 19:45:41 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2016 19:45:41 GMT
    Content-Length: 1456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using Caching then SerivceStack isn't doing the Compression and so it must be done by IIS/ASP.NET which you should be able to disable in your Web.config with:

```
<system.webServer>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Incidentally the way clients ask for responses to be compressed is by using the `Accept-Encoding` HTTP Request Header, e.g:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
```

If the client doesn't include a `Accept-Encoding` the server shouldn't return compressed results.